# My Signed APK not install in Samsung, miA1 and Oppo F1

Tags: android, apk, signed, android-install-apk

ERROR MESSAGE:

> You not have a proprer app for viewing this content.

[image: Sumsang Mobile>>When i click on open not give installed error]

[image: In Oppo F1]

Comment: Your APK might be corrupted or using API version lower then required could you show me your manifest file please and gradle file if available

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/safe-install-android-apps-unknown-sources/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Is not an Apk Problem, Nor a Signing Problem, Some Devices, Especially Samsung ones have an App Management Tool built-in. And Most Users don't even know about such thing. These App Management Features are just Messing with Google Play Store to Kepp the Device Alive and Prevent Any Crash.

But there is a setting in Samsung devices which gives the user option to deactivate this "Management" tool.

Also, If you have Published your Application on Google Play, Go your Google Play Console, There is an Option which tells you on Which devices your App can be installed and Used. It gives you a very high precision estimate of Device Reachability.

Your APK is Fine, Don't Worry.